# Is there a way to integrate spring roo with couchdb

Tags: couchdb, spring-roo

Is there a simple way to customize persistence of spring roo projects for supporting Couchdb ?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there is no simple way to integrate Spring Roo with CouchDB.

The page [Why Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/roo/why) indicates that Roo has REST support, so my guess is that CouchDB integration is not difficult, however I would not assume it is "simpler" either.

Also, the [Spring data](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data) project has planned CouchDB support, but nothing released at this time.

Answer (score 1):

With the 1.2 Release, Spring Roo now has support for MongoDB, if you need immediate NoSQL support you can move into MongoDB -- provided it caters your requirements expected by CouchDB.

You can find some of the comparisons below.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Comparing+Mongo+DB+and+Couch+DB

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MongoDB,+CouchDB,+MySQL+Compare+Grid

Cheers!!!